# Can a flyback transformer voltage output be multiplied by a Villard cascade?

Tags: high-voltage, diy, hvdc

I'm trying to keep the setup rather simple for a high voltage power supply I'm making. I'll probably use a ballast to drive the flyback as opposed to perhaps a ZVS board -- feel free to critique this of course. I require 20kV to 50kV for my purposes and was wondering, as the title states, if a flyback voltage output could be multiplied using a standard Villard cascade of maybe 5 stages. I apologize if the question is rather simple.

For reference, [this will likely be the flyback model of choice](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B00TPX6E58).

Answer (score 0):

The older TV sets pretty much did it.

On the other hand, the output of a modern (as much as there are modern CRTs) flyback transformer will be already internally rectified. You may have hard time disassembling it.

Comment: Thank you, I was afraid of this. Do you by any chance know of what year this became prominent and how difficult it might be to acquire an older flyback?

Comment: The Philips K9 chassis TVs used a tripler to multiply the 8kV from the flyback to the required 24kV for the tube. It was prevalent in the late 70's. As to how easy these are to acquire, I have no idea. I dare say there's N.O.S out there somewhere....

Comment: I remember that if I found an old colour TV left out for trash in the 1980s I'd remove the back and snip out the tripler leaving plenty of length on the leads (and if present, remove vacuum tubes).Very very often they would work in any brand of set, and you could buy new 'universal' ones.

Comment: This '[universal tripler](https://www.radio741.com/40621-tv-tripler-fwk-186-5x-universal-ero.html)' 14.87 euros, about $16.80 plus shipping.

Comment: @GFlipflops EHT triplers are on sale in the UK and elsewhere mainly to people restoring or repairing old ("vintage") TVs or monitors. They can be quite expensive but [this one](https://www.donberg.co.uk/catalogue/tv_monitor_spares/triplers/hrt_226bs.html) is only 7.95 UK pounds (around 10.75 US dollars) Shipping extra. Full list from that Irish company [here](https://www.donberg.co.uk/catalogue/tv_monitor_spares/triplers/)